# Get element text using RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I have been struggling with the following lines of code for a few hours now and I still seem to be no closer to a solution.  My code is as follows:

```
#create a list of all the question elements on the page
questions <- remDr$findElements(using = 'xpath', "//div[@class='question-text']")

#get the first question element in the list
question <- questions[1]

#get the text of the question element
question$getElementText()
```

When I debug using RStudio, it looks as though the 'questions' list is populated correctly with all 'question' elements; the 'question' item is populated correctly with the first 'question' element in the list; but many variations on the next line of code, intended to get the text within the question element, all seem to fail, giving the following error:

```
Error in evalq({ : attempt to apply non-function
```

It is possible that the error comes from a different part of the code, but very unlikely, as commenting out that line seems to leave everything else working perfectly.

I would be very grateful for any help you guys and gals might be able to provide.  I'm programming in R using RSelenium - as you can probably tell, I am new to R although I do have very limited experience using Selenium in other environments.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please hover over the R tag - it asks you to provide a minimal reproducible example. Your example is not reproducible: executing the code yields _"Error: object 'remDr' not found"_.

Comment: Apologies Luke, I was trying to provide the shortest possible example to illustrate the problem but obviously I neglected to give a reproducible one. Will try to do better next time.

Comment: Unless you state that you're scraping an internal job resource that can't be shared, posting the URL you're going after wld help folks know if they're assisting someone engaged in theft of intellectual property or not.

Comment: Thanks hrbrmstr, I will bear that in mind, too.  It is difficult to get away from the spectre of intellectual property theft when dealing with scraping code, but this is a project designed to perform some natural language processing over public data (OGL, I think) that is readily available online - and I think there is even an API for those who know how to interact with such things.  Hope this helps people feel more comfortable with providing help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`question` does not have a function called `getElementText`; it's a `list` object instead of a `webElement` object. You need `[[` instead of `[` - check out this example:

```
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver(port=4444L, browser = "phantomjs")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(
  "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833649/get-element-text-using-rselenium")
elems <- remDr$findElements(using = 'xpath', "//a")
elem <- elems[1]
class(elem)
# [1] "list"
elem$getElementText()
# Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

Now

```
elem <- elems[[1]]
class(elem)
# [1] "webElement"
elem$getElementText()
# [[1]]
# [1] "Stack Overflow"
elem$getElementText()[[1]]
# [1] "Stack Overflow"
remDr$close()
rD[["server"]]$stop()
```